# If Else block in Visual Force Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I need to change the breadcrum on my VF Page based on a condition.
Login is:
If value is 'A' display 'AAAA', Otherwise display 'Others'. It's inside a label

Can you please let me know how can I do the same? Thanks.

Regards,
Sudipta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!IF(name=='A','AAAA','Others')}" />
```

Where `name` is your variable.